# Lambda to SQL Translation

Tags: c#, lambda

So I am having fun with myself and C#, by creating a nice Data Access Layer.

I have the following method that translates a simple expression to a SQL where clause, but it only works with the following

```
var people = DataAccessLayer.SelectAllPeople(x => x.Name == "Donald");
//Do some changes to the list
people[0].Surname = "Jansen"
var m = p.BuildUpdateQuerry(people[0], x => x.PersonID == 1);
```

I get the following result

```
UPDATE People SET Name='Donald',Surname='Jansen' WHERE (PersonID = 1)
```

But now If I do the following

```
var m = p.BuildUpdateQuerry(people[0], x => x.PersonID == people[0].PersonID);
```

I get the following Result

```
UPDATE People SET Name='Donald',Surname='Jansen' WHERE (PersonID = value(ReflectionExampleByDonaldJansen.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0).people.get_Item(0).PersonID)
```

My method I am using to Convert the Lambda to String is

```
public static string GetWhereClause<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    var name = expression.Parameters[0].ToString();
    var body = expression.Body.ToString().Replace("\"", "'");
    body = body.Replace("OrElse", "OR");
    body = body.Replace("AndAlso", "AND");
    body = body.Replace("==", "=");
    body = body.Replace("!=", "<>");
    body = body.Replace(string.Format("{0}.", name), "");
    return body;
}
```

So far this is very basic and real fun to do, but I have no Idea how to overcome this XDXD, any Suggestions or Codes ?

Comment: You know that Linq2SQL and Linq2Entities does this?

Comment: Don’t `ToString` the expression tree, but *actually process* the tree completely.

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to work with the string representation of the expression tree. The whole point of the expression trees is that the parsing is already done for you and you get a tree. BTW I think generating code from expression tree is quite complex task, not something to be done in an afternoon

Comment: Yeah I know its not done in an afternoon, I don't expect it to be, I just felt like I was on a wrong track, complex doesn't stop me from doing it, as I said I am doing it for the fun, and also for experience,

@poke cool, I was in debug mode where a saw .ToString() will work, untill I tried to use a property haha

Comment: @Magnus how? would you post an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself, hehehe here is what I did, not finnished yet but maybe someone else might find it usefull

```
    public static string GetWhereClause<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        return GetValueAsString(expression.Body);
    }

    public static string GetValueAsString(Expression expression)
    {
        var value = "";
        var equalty = "";
        var left = GetLeftNode(expression);
        var right = GetRightNode(expression);
        if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Equal)
        {
            equalty = "=";
        }
        if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.AndAlso)
        {
            equalty = "AND";
        }
        if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.OrElse)
        {
            equalty = "OR";
        }
        if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.NotEqual)
        {
            equalty = "<>";
        }
        if (left is MemberExpression)
        {
            var leftMem = left as MemberExpression;
            value = string.Format("({0}{1}'{2}')", leftMem.Member.Name, equalty, "{0}");
        }
        if (right is ConstantExpression)
        {
            var rightConst = right as ConstantExpression;
            value = string.Format(value, rightConst.Value);
        }
        if (right is MemberExpression)
        {
            var rightMem = right as MemberExpression;
            var rightConst = rightMem.Expression as ConstantExpression;
            var member = rightMem.Member.DeclaringType;
            var type = rightMem.Member.MemberType;
            var val = member.GetField(rightMem.Member.Name).GetValue(rightConst.Value);
            value = string.Format(value, val);
        }
        if (value == "")
        {
            var leftVal = GetValueAsString(left);
            var rigthVal = GetValueAsString(right);
            value = string.Format("({0} {1} {2})", leftVal, equalty, rigthVal);
        }
        return value;
    }

    private static Expression GetLeftNode(Expression expression)
    {
        dynamic exp = expression;
        return ((Expression)exp.Left);
    }

    private static Expression GetRightNode(Expression expression)
    {
        dynamic exp = expression;
        return ((Expression)exp.Right);
    }
```

Comment: ,Thanks,very very good,but how to order by parentes and hold parentes statements??/

Comment: Very cool. Do you have any knowledge of where I could implement something like this in java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt extension methods of System.Linq to convert lambda expressions to SQL.
See the code below...

```
var Enames = emp.Employees.Select ( e => e.EmployeeName );
Console.WriteLine ( Enames );
```

The output which I got..

```
SELECT
[Extent1].[EmployeeName] AS [EmployeeName]
FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent1]
```

Comment: I did that already, my output was "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[ReflectionExampleByDonaldJansen.BussinessLogic.Person,System.String]"

Comment: If your Collection is from Entity data model only then you will get the Equalent SQL Query...

Comment: I think your collection is of type IEnumerable.?

Comment: @SanuUthaiahBollera I tired your code, but I got same as Donald. how you got that output?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and started to solve it some time ago. Take a look on LambdaSql.
For now it contains basic scenarios for `select` clause and `where` filters. Setting fields, where, group by, having, order by, joins, nested queries are already supported. Insert, Update and Delete are going to be supported later.

Example:

```
var qry = new SqlSelect
(
    new SqlSelect<Person>()
        .AddFields(p => p.Id, p => p.Name)
        .Where(SqlFilter<Person>.From(p => p.Name).EqualTo("Sergey"))
    , new SqlAlias("inner")
).AddFields<Person>(p => p.Name);

Console.WriteLine(qry.ParametricSql);
Console.WriteLine("---");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("; ", qry.Parameters
    .Select(p => $"Name = {p.ParameterName}, Value = {p.Value}")));
```

Output:

```
SELECT
    inner.Name
FROM
(
    SELECT
        pe.Id, pe.Name
    FROM
        Person pe
    WHERE
        pe.Name = @w0
) AS inner
---
Name = @w0, Value = Sergey
```

See more here https://github.com/Serg046/LambdaSql